# Dart test with roughly equal

Tags: unit-testing, dart

I am now trying to use `dart:test` features.

I can write something like:

`expect(areaUnderCurveWithRectangleRule(f1, 0,1,1000), equals(2));`

But as we know, in float/double calculation, there is no such thing as precise equal. So I am wondering if there is a **roughly equal** testing method? It will return `true` for two double values, if their difference is within a certain `epsilon` (say, 1E-6) or certain percentage?

If not, will this make a good feature request to Dart team?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`dart:test` provides a [`closeTo`](https://pub.dev/documentation/matcher/latest/matcher/closeTo.html) matcher for this purpose:

```dart
expect(areaUnderCurveWithRectangleRule(f1, 0,1,1000), closeTo(2, epsilon));
```

Note that `closeTo` uses an absolute delta, so a single threshold might not be appropriate for floating-point values that have very different magnitudes.

If you instead want a version that compares based on a percentage, it should be easy to wrap `closeTo` with your own function, e.g.:

```dart
Matcher closeToPercentage(num value, double fraction) {
  final delta = value * fraction;
  return closeTo(value, delta);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no standard implementation for this. But you can use the following:

```
expect((x - y).abs() < epsilon, true)
```

for some epsilon you defined earlier

Comment: I tested it and you need two parameters for ```expect```. Hence you should use ```expect(abs(x-y) < epsilon, true);```

Comment: Thank you for the correction

Comment: Just a technicality, but for Dart this would be written: `expect((x - y).abs() < epsilon, true)`

Answer (score 0):

Gives helpful errors, instead of just "false"

```dart
void near(double a, double b, {double eps = 1e-12, bool relative = false}) {
    var bound = relative ? eps*b.abs() : eps;
    expect(a,greaterThanOrEqualTo(b-bound));
    expect(a,lessThanOrEqualTo(b+bound));
}
```