# How to test if two durations are approximately equal in Dart

Tags: dart, testing, duration

I'm trying to test the equality of two durations. Essentially the problem boils down to this:

```dart
test('times are approximately equal', () {
  final expected = DateTime.now();
  final actual = DateTime.now();
  expect(actual, equals(expected));
});
```

This test fails because the times are slightly different:

```
Expected: DateTime:<2021-06-24 14:37:31.946196>  
  Actual: DateTime:<2021-06-24 14:37:31.946197>
```

As long as the durations are within a second of each other that's close enough for me. How do I test that?

*I found the answer so I'm adding it below.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert the durations to milliseconds and then use the `closeTo` matcher.

```dart
test('times are approximately equal', () {
  final expected = DateTime.now();
  final actual = DateTime.now();
  expect(actual.millisecond, closeTo(expected.millisecond, 1000));
});
```

The `1000` is the delta. This means that as long as the expected duration is within 1000 milliseconds of the actual duration, then the test will pass.

*Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61040105/3681880) for pointing me in the right direction.*